# How to save Live Photo to gallery from URL?

Tags: ios, swift, phlivephoto, apple-live-photos

I am currently working on saving live images from an url. But there is not much documents on internet and im stuck to this. 
I have already checked [this code](https://github.com/genadyo/LivePhotoDemo) which is really helpful but unfortunately it only converts the video you record to Live Photo. So what I am trying is, making and saving a Live Photo from an URL which is a mov formatted video.

Hope somebody have a solution. Thank you..

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/browsing_and_modifying_photo_albums

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/livephotoskitjs
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetchangerequest#1656333

keyword is PHAssetChangeRequest
please try.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. But unfortunately these links do not answer my question

Comment: `Live Photos consist of two components: a still photo and a video of the moments just before and after the photo is taken. Using one of the following methods will let you obtain the still photo as a JPG and the video as a MOV file.`
Just try to create an image + video

Comment: Yes, these methods will help me to obtain Jpeg and Mov files. But I need to generate Live Photo from a mov file and the jpeg file.